# Gedit tries to open everything!

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gedit, filemanager

I am having a huge problem. Whenever i try to open a file gedit tries to open it. For example I download something with firefox, i click on the file to open it and gedit opens!
Even in when I want to open a non-java file(images,pdfs,..) from my Eclipse explorer it gedit tries to open. More strangely, whenever, i try to open my home folder or any other folders such as Music, pictures,... from menu it happens!
Can someone help me?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look in your nautilus and tell it on what to do to an executable file.

> Open Nautilus -> Edit -> Preferences -> Behaviour -> Executable Text
>   Files.

Files might not have default application when opening it.

> Right Click on the file -> Properties -> Open with.

Set a default application of that file. If gedit is already selected and you want to change it just go over with your desired application.

Comment: didn't help. gedit still opens my home folder!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the contents of mimeapps.list with:

```
more ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Somewhere in there you will have a settings that says it should open folders or specific files with gedit.

The heading with [default application] can be used to create a new/default mimeapps.list:

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=chromium-browser.desktop
video/x-matroska=smplayer.desktop
video/x-ogm+ogg=smplayer.desktop
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=smplayer.desktop
video/mp4=smplayer.desktop
video/x-msvideo=smplayer.desktop

[Added Associations]
video/x-matroska=smplayer.desktop;
video/x-ogm+ogg=smplayer.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=smplayer.desktop;
video/mp4=smplayer.desktop;
video/x-msvideo=smplayer.desktop;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux for some reason Firefox doesn't recognize real mimetype of binary files and treats them all as `application/octet-stream`. And it opens this mimetype (and thus .pdf, .doc and other files) in a default text editor - Gedit in my case. After long googling and messing with Linux and Firefox config files it turned out that the fix is to delete a line beginning with `application/octet-stream` in mimeapps.list.

On openSUSE 13.2 mimeapps.list was in ~/.config , but on some distros it's in ~/.local/share/applications/ or perhaps in some other place.